# Display values of two arrays in the same table?

Tags: php, mysqli

Trying to build a html table, which will be displaying the buildings a player is allowed build in a game. And there should also be a column that displays how many the player already own.

The code to display the table works as well as all the buildings you can build, but I can't get it to display how many of what building you already own.

Code is a bit messy now with some out commented queries, but I kept them in there to show what I have already tried to get them to display correctly.

EDIT(With C Würtz code):

```
// Fetch buildings
$result = $database->query("SELECT id, name, description, cost, power_use FROM buildings;");
$buildings = array();
while($building = $database->fetch($result)) {
    $buildings[$building['id']] = $building;
}
// Buildings Owned
$buildings_owned = $database->query("SELECT building_id, count(*) as n FROM player_buildings WHERE owner_id = '$user_id'");
    $buildings = array();
        while($owned = $database->fetch($buildings_owned)) {
    $owned_buildings[$owned['id']] = $owned;
} 

    $playerBuildings = array();
    while($owned = $database->fetch($buildings_owned)) {
    $playerBuildings[$owned['buildings_id']] = $owned['n'];
    }

    // Display form 
    echo "For every 10 building you construct, it will also cost you 1 turn!";
    echo "<table style='width:900px;'>
        <tr>
            <th style='border: solid black 1px;width:40% text-align:left;'>Name</th>
            <th style='border: solid black 1px;width:50%;'>Description</th>
            <th style='border: solid black 1px;width:5%;'>Price</th>
            <th style='border: solid black 1px;width:5%;'>Power Usage</th>
            <th style='border: solid black 1px; width:5%;'>Buildins Owned</th>
            <th style='width:5%;'>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>";
        foreach ($buildings as $building) {
                 $bid = $building['id'];
                 $building['player_count'] = isset($playerBuildings[$bid])
               ? $playerBuildings[$bid]
                 : 0;   
            echo "<tr>
                <td style='border: solid black 1px;'>{$building['name']}</td>
                <td style='border: solid black 1px;'>{$building['description']}</td>
                <td style='border: solid black 1px;'>{$building['cost']}</td>
                <td style='border: solid black 1px;'>{$building['power_use']}</td>
                <td style='border: solid black 1px;'>{$owned['amount']} </td>
                <td>    
                    <form action='$self_link' method='POST'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='building_id' value='$id' />
                        <input style='width:40px' type='number' name='amount' value='amount' />
                        <input type='submit' name='build' value='Build' />
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>";
        }
        
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: you can use a join query for do this, if you want to make query separate then use some array joining function like: array_combine(), array_merge().

Comment: i tried using a join query, but i didt get it to work. No values was displayed at all then. Not sure if i called them correctly tho..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query is like `SELECT id, name, etc FROM buildings;` to PHP array `$buildings`.

The second could be like `SELECT buildings_id, count(*) as n FROM player_buildings WHERE owner_id = :user_id;`. Then order the PHP array:

```
$playerBuildings = [];
while($owned = $database->fetch($buildings_owned)) {
   $playerBuildings[$owned['buildings_id']] = $owned['n'];
}
```

In the view, just loop on `$buildings` and check if there is a relative `$playerBuildings`.

```
foreach ($buildings as $building) {
   $bid = $building['id'];
   $building['player_count'] = isset($playerBuildings[$bid])
       ? $playerBuildings[$bid]
       : 0;
   // render something
}
```

Comment: I tried adding this the best i could, while i dont get any errors the table is empy..

Comment: You fetch twice on the second query. Remove the 4 lines after `$buildings_owned =  $database->query(...);`

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT count(*) as owned_buildings FROM player_buildings WHERE owner_id = '$user_id'
```

Comment: explain a bit around your answer